# Is it OK to embed mac key in cipher

Tags: aes, mac

I am in a case where I can not share a mac key, only the encryption key. I need to provide authentication and integrity with the cipher so I would like to send a mac with the cipher. I cannot use AES-GCM for example, I am limited to AES-CBC.

Is it ok to embed mac key in the cipher in this case in term of security?

For example, like this:

```
encrypt(text, key)
  mac_key = generateRandom256bitsKey()
  cipher = aes_encrypt(mac_key + text, key)
  return hmac(cipher, mac_key) + cipher

decrypt(cipher, hmac_sig, key)
  decrypted = aes_decrypt(cipher, key)
  mac_key = decrypted[0, 255]
  if (hmac(cipher, mac_key) != hmac_sig)
    return null;
  return decrypted[256, decrypted.length - 1]
```

Thanks,

Comment: Does using a 256 bit mac key imply that you expect 256 bits of IND-CCA2 security? Why aren't you using a KDF for splitting the key you already have into one content encryption key (for AES) and one content authentication key (for HMAC)?

Comment: Yes it must follow ind-cca2. If i split the key I can't change the hmac key and i will reuse it for the next messages of communication. Is it secure ?

Comment: Key splitting will be secure, provided that you use a random per-message IV, instead of the random per-message mac key.

Comment: Just to be sure. If I use same encryption key + random uniq iv + same hmac key for each message, does it will be secure?

Comment: That would be a conventional construct, so yes. The mac key should be different (ideally independent) from the aes key, but it doesn't have to change with each message.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To answer the question, no, you can't hope to get 256-bit IND-CCA2, by encrypting a 256 bit mac key.

Suppose you are playing the IND-CCA2 game and have got to the point where you have submitted two plain text messages $M_1, M_2$ and have got a challenge cipher text $C$. Your job is to decide which plain text $C$ corresponds to, with less than $2^{256}$ calls to the decryption oracle. Since you may choose both the mac and randomize the mac key (by modifying the first blocks of cipher text), the birthday paradox applies, and you are limited only by the collision resistance of the underlying hash function.

Depending on potential vulnerabilities in the underlying hash function, being able to modify the second half of the mac key, while leaving the first 128 bits of the mac key unmodified, might entail vulnerability to chose key attacks.

A more conventional IND-CCA2 secure construct would be:

```
encrypt(text, enc_key, mac_key)
  iv = generaterandom()
  cipher = iv + aes_cbc_encrypt(enc_key, iv, text)
  return cipher + hmac(mac_key, cipher)

decrypt(cipher, mac, enc_key, mac_key)
  if (hmac(mac_key, cipher) != mac)
    return null;
  iv = cipher[0..127]
  return aes_cbc_decrypt(enc_key,iv,cipher[128..cipher.length-1])
```

Please note that the usual caveats regarding all block chaining modes for 128 bit block sizes, and CBC mode in particular, apply regarding maximum amount of cipher text and maximum number of messages, before you start loosing security.

If you may choose the enc key and the mac key independently at random, that would be ideal. If not, but you are limited by a fixed size key material (the key in your question), you may extend it and split it, using a standard KDF, such as [HKDF](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5869).

Please also note that if timing attacks apply, you might want to go ahead and decrypt the cipher text, even if the hmac verification fails (but still discard it in case of mac verification failure). However, if timing attacks against the application layer apply, you would anyway have to put in counter measures at that level.

Comment: @HenrickHellström is it ok to use PBKDF?

Comment: @Flo354 Yes, use it two times with a different "salt" (where you would normally use Info, or OtherInfo in a KBKDF) to derive two different keys or use SHA-512 and use the first part of the output for the encryption key and the second part for the mac key. You can simply set the iteration count to 1, there is no need for key strengthening if you already start with a symmetric key of sufficient strength.

Comment: Since I'm always limited by the data shared, is it ok to use first 128bits aes key as password and next 128bits key as salt with SHA-512?

Comment: No, the "salt" (or rather, label) might be a constant string, e.g. "CEK" for deriving the aes key and "CAK" for deriving the mac key. The only requirement is that they are different.